# what's the meaning for the upper tilt symbol in convex optimization for?

Tags: convex-optimization

I am kind of confused by the h with upper tilt symbol here: [property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dem4.png)

Thank you!

Comment: By "h with an upper tilt", do you mean $h'()$ or $\tilde{h}()$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, by "h with an upper tilt", you mean $h'()$, then that notation simply means the derivative of $h()$.

If you mean $\tilde{h}(x)$, the symbol is called a "tilde."  This notation isn't completely standard but is used by some authors in convex optimization to mean the extension of a function with a limited domain to all of $R^{n}$ by defining the function to be $+\infty$ if $x$ is outside of the domain.  If the domain of $h$ is $D$, then in this notation:

$\tilde{h}(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
h(x) & x \in D \\
+\infty & x \notin D 
\end{array}
\right.$

Hopefully, the author of these slides defined the notation that they were using early in the presentation.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is meant by $\tilde{h}$ in this case.